Google sheets Take away price if box is ticked
I am trying to take away the price from the total if the box is ticked.
Can someone explain this to me?

I tried to do some conditional formatting but I'm sure what I'm doing as I'm not very good at formulas.

Use SUMIFS() function like =SUMIFS(G8:G13,B8:B13,FALSE).

Put in B14 cell this formula
=SUMIF(B8:B13;TRUE;G8:G13)

Cheers


Take away price if box is ticked

try:
=SUMPRODUCT(G8:G13; B8:B13=FALSE)


